# Сравнить производительность двух ПК

Tags: windows, ubuntu, железо, нагрузочное-тестирование

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, программу, которая сможет оценить производительность двух ПК, чтобы их сравнить. 
Особенность в том что на одном ПК - Ubunbu 16.04, а на втором - Win 10.

Чтобы сравнение было бы релевантно, программа должна поддерживать обе операционки. ПК не будут использоваться в играх, поэтому тест под игры также не подойдет.

Comment: Сравнивать нужно в тех задачах, для которых планируется использовать комп. В одних задачах может оказаться быстрее один комп, в других задачах — другой

Comment: Да, так и будем делать. Но необходима одна программа, которая в баллах оценит производительность в одинаковых условиях.

Comment: И эти баллы окажутся бесполезными, потому что на реальных задачах производительность может оказаться совершенно другой :)

Comment: Согласен, но надо от чего то отталкиваться

Comment: Ну так просто взять и измерить в тех задачах, для которых планируется использовать комп

Answer (score 1):

Как пример, можно прогнать обе машины через `stress-ng` и сравнить показатели:

```
~$ stress-ng --cpu 4 --vm 2 --hdd 1 --fork 8 --switch 4 --timeout 5m --metrics-brief

stress-ng: info:  [29834] dispatching hogs: 4 cpu, 8 fork, 1 hdd, 4 switch, 2 vm
stress-ng: info:  [29834] successful run completed in 305.97s (5 mins, 5.97 secs)
stress-ng: info:  [29834] stressor       bogo ops real time  usr time  sys time   bogo ops/s   bogo ops/s
stress-ng: info:  [29834]                           (secs)    (secs)    (secs)   (real time) (usr+sys time)
stress-ng: info:  [29834] cpu              166994    300.03    853.33      1.35       556.59       195.39
stress-ng: info:  [29834] fork             229293    300.00     27.66     28.24       764.31      4101.84
stress-ng: info:  [29834] hdd             1265641    305.97      0.40     45.23      4136.55     27737.04
stress-ng: info:  [29834] switch        183002493    300.00     69.93    890.87    610007.81    190468.87
stress-ng: info:  [29834] vm              3185704    300.03    424.74      5.38     10617.78      7406.55
```

Программа идет с большим набором тестов, можно собрать оптимальных набор.

Как пользователь Fedora могу посоветовать применить ключевое слово "benchmark"  к поиску пакетов и почитать описание:

```
~$ dnf search benchmark
Last metadata expiration check: 19 days, 2:39:53 ago on Thu 30 Aug 2018 22:06:43 BST.

ohc-benchmark.noarch : OHC benchmark executable
jmh-core-benchmarks.noarch : JMH Core Benchmarks
metrics-benchmarks.noarch : Benchmarks for Metrics
lucene-benchmark.noarch : Lucene Benchmarking Module
junit-benchmarks.noarch : Code benchmarking in JUnit4
ocaml-benchmark.i686 : Benchmarking module for OCaml
ocaml-benchmark.x86_64 : Benchmarking module for OCaml
xstream-benchmark.noarch : benchmark module for xstream
nodejs-benchmark.noarch : A JavaScript benchmarking library
junit-benchmarks-javadoc.noarch : Javadoc for junit-benchmarks
mustache-java-benchmarks.noarch : Benchmarks for Mustache.java
ocaml-benchmark-devel.i686 : Development files for ocaml-benchmark
ocaml-benchmark-devel.x86_64 : Development files for ocaml-benchmark
intel-mpi-benchmarks-license.noarch : License of Intel MPI benchmarks
libguestfs-benchmarking.x86_64 : Benchmarking utilities for libguestfs
python2-pytest-benchmark.noarch : A py.test fixture for benchmarking code
python3-pytest-benchmark.noarch : A py.test fixture for benchmarking code
rubygem-benchmark-ips-doc.noarch : Documentation for rubygem-benchmark-ips
intel-mpi-benchmarks-mpich.x86_64 : Intel MPI benchmarks compiled against mpich
rubygem-benchmark-ips.noarch : An iterations per second enhancement to Benchmark
intel-mpi-benchmarks-openmpi.x86_64 : Intel MPI benchmarks compiled against openmpi
```

**Ссылки**

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~cking/stress-ng/

Comment: подскажите, данная программа работает с Win 10?

Comment: @R2D2-X можете с флешки запустить

Comment: спасибо, попробуем.